# Rcpp: Calling function with object as argument

Tags: c++11, rcpp

I have a function in Rcpp, which creates a very long map-structure within a class. I've given a simple example of it below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class A{
private:
  std::map<int, int> m_map;
public:
  void fill_map(const size_t limit){
    for(size_t i=0; i<limit; ++i){
      m_map[i] = i;
    }
  }
  size_t size_map(){return m_map.size();}
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void func1(const size_t limit) {
  A a;
  a.fill_map(limit);
}

/* NOT WORKING */
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void func2(A a)
{
  std::cout << a.size_map() << "\n";
}
/* NOT WORKING */
```

Say I call `func1(1e7)`, which fills up the map in the `a`-object. I need to pass this `A`-object to other functions as shown above with `func2`.

However, my example with `func2` doesn't work. Within the `Rcpp`-framework, what is the correct and most efficient approach to call `func2` with an object defined in a previous function?

Comment: You question is more complex than it appears. It depends what you want to do. I understand, with your code that you want to construct a `A` at the c++ level, then print it later at the R level without returning such object at the R level. `func1` must at least return a pointer on `A`. Please be more specific on what you want to do and why.

Comment: @JRR You are exactly correct. Because the object is so big, I'd rather not return it to the R-level, but keep it at C++-level until all operations are done.

Comment: I cannot help you much more because I never work like that. But basically `func1` must return a pointer to `a`. `a` must be created with `new` otherwise it is destroyed at the end of `func1`. `func2` must receive a pointer to `a`. With `Rcpp` you can look for external pointer class. And because `a` is allocated with `new` you must `delete` it somewhere

Answer (score 5):

C++ code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class A
{
  private:
    std::map<int, int> m_map;

  public:
    void fill_map(const size_t limit)
    {
      for(size_t i=0; i<limit; ++i)
      {
        m_map[i] = i;
      }
    }

    size_t size_map(){return m_map.size();}
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<A> func1(const size_t limit)
{
  XPtr<A> ptr(new A(), true);
  ptr->fill_map(limit);
  return(ptr);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void func2(XPtr<A> ptr)
{
  Rcout << ptr->size_map() << std::endl;
}
```

R code

```
a = func1(10)
func2(a)
```

`a` being an `External pointer`.